# Não consigo realizar um Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, relacionamento

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a como eu devo montar o `SELECT` para uma determinada função.

O cenário é o seguinte:

Tenho 4 tabelas: `Tab_Pessoa - Tab_Cliente - Tab_Autorizado - Tab_Cliente_Autorizado`.
De forma que a `Tab_Pessoa` se relaciona com a de `Tab_Cliente` e `Tab_Autorizado` -
A `Tab_Cliente_Autorizado` se relaciona com a de `Tab_Cliente` e `Tab_Autorizado`.
De maneira sucinta `Tab_Pessoa` tem o campo nome.

Eu quero obter a seguinte Informação: **O nome do autorizado de um determinado cliente.**

De outra forma pra ficar mais claro:

Na `Tab_Pessoa` tem os seguintes registros:

```
cod_pessoa  | Nome
1           | Luis
2           | Carlos
3           | Paulo
```

Na `Tab_Cliente` tem os seguintes registros:

```
cod_cliente | cod_pessoa 
1           | 1
```

Na `Tab_Autorizado` tem os seguintes registros:

```
cod_autorizado  | cod_pessoa 
1               | 2
2               | 3
```

Na `Tab_Cliente_Autorizado` tem os seguintes registros:

```
cod_cliente_autorizado | cod_cliente | cod_autorizado 
1                      | 1           | 1
2                      | 1           | 2
```

Eu quero que com `cod_cliente = 1` eu consiga o nome do autorizado dele: Carlos e Paulo

Já montei diversos `SELECT's` mas não obtive êxito, na minha mente inicialmente seria esse `SELECT` seria dessa forma:

```
Select pes.nome from tab_Cliente_Autorizado cli_aut 
inner join tab_Cliente cli on cli.cod_cliente = cli_aut.cod_cliente
inner join tab_Pessoa pes on cli.cod_pessoa = pes.cod_pessoa
where cli_aut.cod_cliente = 1
```

Mas o que eu obtenho é o nome do cliente 2 vezes.

Desde já fico grato com qualquer sugestão.

**Atualização - Com script das tabelas**

--**Tabela Pessoa**

```
go
create table tab_Pessoa(
cod_pessoa int identity(1,1) not null,
nome nvarchar(200) null,
constraint pk_pessoa Primary Key (cod_pessoa))
go
```

--**Tabela Cliente**

```
go
create table tab_Cliente(
cod_cliente int identity(1,1) not null,
cod_pessoa int not null,
constraint pk_cliente Primary Key (cod_cliente),
constraint fk_tab_Cliente_tab_Pessoa foreign key(cod_pessoa) references tab_Pessoa(cod_pessoa))
```

--**Tabela Autorizado**

```
go
create table tab_Autorizado(
cod_autorizado int identity(1,1) not null,
cod_pessoa int not null,
constraint pk_autorizado Primary Key (cod_autorizado),
constraint fk_tab_Autorizado_tab_Pessoa foreign key(cod_pessoa) references tab_Pessoa(cod_pessoa))
go
```

--**Tabela Cliente - Autorizado**

```
go
create table tab_Cliente_Autorizado(
cod_cliente_autorizado int identity(1,1) not null,
cod_cliente int not null,
cod_autorizado int not null,
constraint pk_cliente_autorizado Primary Key (cod_cliente_autorizado),
constraint fk_tab_Cliente_Autorizado_tab_Autorizado foreign key(cod_autorizado) references tab_Autorizado(cod_autorizado),
constraint fk_tab_Cliente_Autorizado_tab_Cliente foreign key(cod_cliente) references tab_Cliente(cod_cliente))
go
```

Comment: Velho, pode mostrar o script das tabelas? Ajudaria bastante, creio que o problema está no relacionamento... caso veja necessidade, crie seu exemplo do que está acontecendo ai: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Veja detalhes de como editar aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não precisa envolver a tabela **Tab_Cliente** no SELECT porque você não vai buscar nenhum dado dela.

Você precisa obter os códigos de autorização de um cliente na tabela **Tab_Cliente_Autorizado** e com base nestes códigos buscar as pessoas autorizadas deste cliente na tabela **Tab_Autorizado**, e com base nos códigos das pessoas encontradas você precisa obter os nomes das pessoas em **Tab_Pessoa**.

Então o relacionamento poderia ser representado assim: **Tab_Cliente_Autorizado -> Tab_Autorizado -> Tab_Pessoa**. O SELECT fica assim:

```
select 
    Tab_Pessoa.Nome
from
    Tab_Cliente_Autorizado
    JOIN Tab_Autorizado on Tab_Autorizado.cod_autorizado = Tab_Cliente_Autorizado.cod_autorizado
    JOIN Tab_Pessoa on Tab_Pessoa.cod_pessoa  = Tab_Autorizado.cod_pessoa
where
    Tab_Cliente_Autorizado.cod_cliente = 1
```

Observação: se suas tabelas contém apenas estes dados, você não precisa da tabela **Tab_Autorizado**. Em vez disso, poderia relacionar a pessoa autorizada diretamente em **Tab_Cliente_Autorizado**. Esta tabela ficaria assim:

```
cod_cliente_autorizado | cod_cliente | cod_pessoa 
1                      | 1           | 2
2                      | 1           | 3
```

Outra observação: você não precisa do prefixo *"Tab_"* nos nomes das tabelas.

Comment: É isso mesmo, muito obrigado mesmo. Eu não tinha conhecimento que podia utilizar somente o join.

Comment: Agora que eu olhei com mais atenção, vi a complexidade do select que você fez. Parabéns nunca ia pensa nisso.

Comment: @LuisFelipeMicaideJesus De nada. Veja meu update na resposta com uma observação sobre a sua modelagem. Quanto a usar somente a palavra **JOIN**, trata-se de um atalhao para o **INNER JOIN**. Ou seja, se o tipo e direção do JOIN (*inner*, ou *outer left* ou *outer right*) forem omitidos, o padrão é assumido: *inner join*.